# Adding two next rows data to the current row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a stock dataframe:

```
       Date     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0  01.05.2018  1.20821  1.20821  1.20793  1.20794  138.96
1  01.05.2018  1.20794  1.20795  1.20787  1.20788  119.61
2  01.05.2018  1.20788  1.20793  1.20770  1.20779  210.42
3  01.05.2018  1.20779  1.20791  1.20779  1.20789   77.51
4  01.05.2018  1.20789  1.20795  1.20789  1.20792   56.97
```

I want to copy the next two rows to the current row. Or more clear, each row in the new dataframe should have the next two rows data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat({i: df.shift(-i) for i in range(3)}, axis=1)
```

---

Generalized

```
n = 3
pd.concat({i: df.shift(-i) for i in range(n)}, axis=1).iloc[:len(df) - n + 1]
```

Comment: Great! and another question: How can I shift all rows but except one. I mean exclude on row for shifting.

Comment: Copying all rows but one row.

Comment: Copying "Date,High,Open,Low,Close" but not "Volume"